# Get specific line below grepped line

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sql

I have a challenging issue that I am facing below

I have the below text in a file:

```
create table "ctronsys".activity_codes
(
   code_list_id varchar(8),
   code_id varchar(10),
   record_type varchar(1),
   active_status_ind varchar(1),
   security_level varchar(1),
   short_description varchar(10),
   long_description varchar(30),
   record_class varchar(1),
   owner_id varchar(4),
   modify_user_id varchar(3),
   modify_date date,
   create_user_id varchar(3),
   create_date date
) in datadbs extent size 16 next size 16 lock mode row;
```

My aim is to grep for the below line in the text file:

```
create table "ctronsys".activity_codes
```

and using the above to retrieve the line below:

```
) in datadbs extent size 16 next size 16 lock mode row;
```

Note that the number of lines to search below is not specific according to table structures

I have the below command, which allows me to print a column within a line above the grepped line using awk, however this only prints a single column within that line whereas I would like to print the entire line:

```
cat table_structure | awk -v key="datadbs" '/^create/ {val=$3} $3 == key {print val;}'
```

Comment: I want to grep for "create table "ctronsys".activity_codes" and print the line by seraching for ) in datadbs extent size, because that line might not be the last line the the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="\n[()]"; RS=";" } /^create table "ctronsys".activity_codes/ { print $NF }' file
 in datadbs extent size 16 next size 16 lock mode row
```

We divide the file contents into `;`-separated records.  Each record is divided into fields based on the `(` or `)` at the beginning of a line.

When reading the file, the first record will be the full contents of this particular file.

The first field of that record is

```
create table "ctronsys".activity_codes
```

The second field is

```
   code_list_id varchar(8),
   code_id varchar(10),
   record_type varchar(1),
   active_status_ind varchar(1),
   security_level varchar(1),
   short_description varchar(10),
   long_description varchar(30),
   record_class varchar(1),
   owner_id varchar(4),
   modify_user_id varchar(3),
   modify_date date,
   create_user_id varchar(3),
   create_date date
```

And the last field is

```
 in datadbs extent size 16 next size 16 lock mode row
```